# Почему пропадает Wi-Fi на роутере ASUS RT-10NLX?

Tags: wifi, роутер, железо, asus

Имеется в наличии локальная сеть.
Кабель от провайдера идет в роутер ASUS RT-10NLX, из которого кабелем поступает интернет на мой ПК и smart-tv. Имеется wi-fi антенна также.

**Суть проблемы:** все устройства, подключенные по вай-фай постоянно имеют некоторые проблемы с работой в сети, а именно - пропадание подключения.
Иногда придя домой, я пытаюсь подключиться к вай-фаю с помощью телефона, но не могу - "Попытка получения IP-адреса..." и так бесконечно, пока его/их не перезагрузишь.
На ноутбуке и другом стационарном ПК (использует вай-фай модуль внешний) постоянно пропадает вай-фай с неопределенным интервалом. На ноутбуке стоит Win7, на стационарном ПК - windows xp, он уже древний. Везде режимы энергосбережния выключены, вроде как.
Куда копать, как быть? Без понятия что происходит :(

Comment: Как насчёт смены прошивки?

Comment: никогда этим не занимался, но наслышан про последующие "кирпичи" после неумельцев, вроде меня... + пара минут в гугле ничего пока не дала.